# submit value from number field to variable in blur action (EXTJS)

Tags: extjs, blur, gridpanel

i want to submit value from NumberField in gridpanel to variable, i use blur action . but when i one click to blur action, value not in to variable. when i click one more time for blur action, the value in to variable. 
this my code :

```
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    id: 'frm_form_tengah_gridpanel',
                    title: 'A. Rencana dan Target Kinerja ',
                    width: 700,
                    height: 200,
                    border: 1,
                    margin: '10 0 10 0',
                    store: dtlstore,
                    columns: [ 

                        {header:'Kegiatan',id:'frm_kegiatan',dataIndex: 'kegiatan', width: 350,align: 'left',renderer:test,flex:1,editor: new Ext.form.TextArea({id: 'a'}), tdCls:'wrap-text'},
                        {header:'Target',id:'frm_target',dataIndex: 'target', width: 350,align: 'left',renderer:test,flex:1,editor: new Ext.form.TextArea({id: 'b'}), tdCls:'wrap-text'},
                        {header:'Pencapaian',id:'frm_pencapaian',dataIndex: 'pencapaian',  
                            width: 350, align:'left', 
                            renderer:test,flex:1, 
                            editor: new Ext.form.NumberField({id:'z',  
                                listeners: {

                          blur: function(){

                           var grid = Ext.getCmp('frm_form_tengah_gridpanel');                                  

                            var b ;
                            var c  =0;
                            var i=0;

                           for (i; i<grid.getStore().getCount(); i++){
                                 count = grid.getStore().getAt(i).data.pencapaian;

                                b = parseFloat(count);
                                 c = (c + b);

                                 console.log(i);
                                 console.log(c);

                              }   


                                var d = c/grid.getStore().getCount();
                                 console.log(d);
```

someone can help me ?   Thanks.

Comment: i'm have been try use getValues() and it's worked, but i can't sum all valus from 2 number field i have. in this case i load from store to gridpanel and have 2 data. example:

name      ||  qty                              
manggo         10
apple          20
total          30   

when i'm edit manggo with use get values()

name       || qty
manggo        50 
apple         20
total         100 => 50+50

Comment: when i push enter button after write in numberfield, value save into variable on one blur. but when i use mouse click for blur action, value not save  to variable in one click. always use 2 clik for blur action until the value save into variable. someone can help me ?